# Java Springboot JPA joining multiple tables

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, many-to-many

I'm new to Java Springboot and I want to join multiple tables.

I have this MySQL schema :

```sql
CREATE TABLE `users`
(
    `id`                 int              NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `email`              varchar(128)     NOT NULL,
    `nickname`           varchar(128)     NOT NULL,
    `password`           varchar(256)     NOT NULL,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
    UNIQUE KEY `nickname` (`nickname`)
);

CREATE TABLE `organizations` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `org_abilities`
(
    `id`          int          NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `key`         varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    `description` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `idx_key` (`key`) USING BTREE
);

CREATE TABLE `org_permissions`
(
    `id`              int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_user`         int NOT NULL,
    `id_organization` int NOT NULL,
    `id_ability`      int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `id_organization` (`id_organization`),
    KEY `id_user` (`id_user`),
    KEY `users_permissions_ibfk_2` (`id_ability`),
    CONSTRAINT `org_permissions_ibfk_0` FOREIGN KEY (`id_organization`) REFERENCES `organizations` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `org_permissions_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_user`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `org_permissions_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_ability`) REFERENCES `org_abilities` (`id`)
);
```

Where my table org_permissions represent all abilities that a user has within an organization.

I have created the corresponding Java classes. I have a JPA to fetch the datas from the DB to the classes.

I want in my `Organization` class to have a field `Map<long, List<Pair<long, String>>> managers` which map an **id_user** to a list of tuple of abilities where the tuple is **(id_ability, org_ability.key)**.

Finally I use DTO to send my response, and I want my response to look like that :

```
{
    id : _id_organization,
    name : "organisation name",
    managers : {
          id_user: [(id_ability, key), (id_ability, key)],
          id_user:[(id_ability, key), (id_ability, key)]
      }
}
```

**For example:**

```sql
SELECT op.*, oa.* FROM org_permissions as op
JOIN org_abilities oa on oa.id = op.id_ability
JOIN organizations o on o.id = op.id_organization
JOIN users u on u.id = op.id_user;
```

[image: MySQL query result]

Here, user with id *1* is member of organization **1** and **2**. for organization **1** user *1* has the `CREATE_EVENTS` and `DELETE_EVENTS` abilities and for organization **2** he only have the `DELETE_EVENTS` ability.

When getting all the organization I want this result :

```
[{
    id : 1,
    name : "Org1",
    managers : {
      1: [(1, "CREATE_EVENT"), (2,"CREATE_EVENT")]
    }
},
{
    id : 2,
    name : "Org2",
    managers : {
      1: [(2,"CREATE_EVENT")]
    }
}]
```

Thanks for your help, I'm a bit lost with the High level of springboot and JPA

P.S.: I tried to ask to chat GPT but nothing was concluent

Comment: adding a one to many field in the  org_permissions entity class for each join might be what you are looking for (at least from what I can tell from your example query). Also, you can always try running native queries!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I add the @OneToMany in my org_permission entity class, but how to make my Organization class link with the OrganizationPermission class without having a whole Object User or OrganizatioAbility ? I just want to store a Map=id_user->List<Pair<>>. Maybe is not possible or I miss understood how JPA works